# creating virtual hosts does not work properly on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2, dns

i have created a virtual host on my virtual machine.
The Host does not resolves properly.
These are the steps i have done:

1. /etc/hosts *added 127.0.0.1 example.com*
2. *created example.com.conf in sites-available* and loaded sexample.com.conf via a2ensite and reloaded apache.

My conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But example.com redirects me to the reals Domain with IP 93.184.216.34.
My /etc/nsswitch.conf file looks like this:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files  dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

My /etc/resolve.conf loks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search *****.com
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem caused because i have to work nehind a proxy.
If you work behind a proxy /etc/hosts does not work.
You have to ignore the hosts in etc/hosts.

The simplest and fastest way to do this is setting up no_proxy in `/etc/environment`.
To do this edit `/etc/environment` and add or append no_proxy like : `no_proxy= "localhost, 127.0.0.1, example.com"` in my case i had to set proxy settings on Firefox aswell.
And restart your machine.
If you want to check your proxy settings you can run following command `env | grep proxy`.